# Cross platform portable dev environment suggestions

Tags: windows, macos, mobile, cross-platform, development-environment

I'm looking for some ideas wrt setting up a portable/sharable multi-platform development rig targeting Mac/Windows/iOS/Android/Electron apps. Some basic constraints (unless one can suggest a good way to wiggle around them):

- Run on my MacBook Pro for portability so I can take it with me when I'm off campus.
- Support both macOS and Windows dev environments (macOS needed for iOS and macOS Electron builds, Windows needed for Windows and Windows Electron builds).
- Windows and macOS dev environments need access to common/shared directory structure for common sources and cross-platform builds, especially for a mono-repo environment.
- VM or container (Docker?) based so I can easily back up, checkpoint, and share dev system images with other developers, especially for on-boarding new developers with minimal hassle getting them set up.

I'm kind of kicking around the idea of using two VMs with Parallels/VMWare/VirtualBox, one running macOS and exporting part of its file system to the other which would run Windows. Hoping it would be feasible to run two dev VMs on a 16GB MacBook Pro.

Another idea I'm pondering is doing cloud builds, but I want to minimize excessive data usage when I'm on a wireless/slow telco/wifi connection.

Haven't yet thought out any of these ideas in great detail, so I'm wide open to suggestions.

Any better ideas?

Thanks,

Mike